# Hierarchy structure in Laravel

Tags: laravel, hierarchy

I have implemented subscriber hierarchy structure in my Laravel application.

My Database structure is: subscriber table with primary key id and parent column parent_id and Eloquent relationship in Subscriber Model:

```
// Each subscriber may have one parent
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subscriber::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->with('parent');
}

//each subscriber may have many children
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(Subscriber::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->with('children');
}
```

To get multilevel hierarchy data, I have used recursive function and above relationship method to get parent and children data like.

```
public function getChildren($subscriber=null) {
    $subscriber = $subscriber?:$this->subscriber;
    $children = collect([]);
    return $this->getChildrenRecursive($children, $subscriber);
}

private function getChildrenRecursive($children, $subscriber) {
    foreach ($subscriber->children as $child) {
        $children->push($child);
        $this->getChildrenRecursive($children, $child);
    }
    return $children;
}
```

Initially, I did not notice the case of cyclic loop/self-linking in multi-level hierarchy. If accidently, cyclic loop exist in data.

```
$subscriber->children();
$subscriber->parent();
```

The above method goes infinite loop and server crashes after with Allowed memory size exhausted. And Laravel eloquent does not handle cyclic loop or self-linking by default. What is the best way to handle these scenario in Laravel?

And another issue of using recursive function to get all the child or parent node in multi-level (N-level) hierarchy is performance. How to increase performance? I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which do you do more - read or write the hierarchical data? If you read it more, consider using a nested set instead. It's extremely efficient at reading the data tree.

Comment: Mostly, reading the data in a tree.

Comment: Perhaps look at something like [this](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset).

Comment: Thanks @fubar. But sometimes, we have break the subscriber and link it to another parent. How hard is to break the child node and connect with the another parent node using Nested Set model?

Comment: There are example queries if you read the README file for the linked repo. Writing updates to the tree is certainly more expensive the structure you have now, but that's the trade-off with being able to read an entire tree with a single query.